# invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' and 'vector<int>::iterator' (aka '__wrap_iter<int *>'))

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, cout

During the execution of the program the above error is displayed.

Aim of the code is to print "Yes" if the number 'h' is present in v vector and its corresponding index . If the number is not present you have to print "No" followed by the index of the next smallest number just greater than that number.

Thank you for help in advance.

```
    cin >> h; //value to be searched in vector v
    vector<int>::iterator lower;
    lower=lower_bound(v.begin(),v.end(),h);
    if(*(lower) == h){
        cout<<"Yes "<<lower<<endl;
    }else{
        cout<<"No "<<lower<<endl;
```

Comment: In the comparison you're dereferencing the iterator `lower`. You need to do that when printing as well.

Comment: You also need to check in the `else` case that the iterator can be dereferenced, if all the items in the vector are less than `h` then `*lower` would be an error.

Comment: @john if item not found till the end of the list then lower will automatically point the very last integer of vector. I don't think it would be a problem

Comment: [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) returns the "last" iterator, which in your case is `v.end()`, which can't be dereferenced. And you need to check for this before attempting to dereference the iterator in the condition as well.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  It would be appreciated if you help me in understand that why we cannot dereference v.end().

Comment: Because the "end" iterator is one *beyond* the last element of the container. That makes iterators work like zero-base indexing. You know that an array of `N` elements have indexes from `0` to `N - 1`? It's the same thing here, the "end" is outside the range of valid elements. Any decent book, tutorial or class should have contained that information.

Comment: @YashpriyadeepKatta [Recommended book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)